# .htaccess RewriteRule cause an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: .htaccess, symfony4

I'm hosting a Symfony project, and i want to redirect an unique url to another one. But i get a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

I don't understand how can my code make a redirect loop.

Here is my .htaccess, i took a default for Symfony then i added this after *RewriteEngine On* :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/admin [L,R=301,NC]
```

And the full .htaccess :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sci-hl.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sci-hl.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sci-hl.com/admin [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I'm just wanting to redirect users when the go to 
[http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com] to *https://www.example.com/admin*

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the destination path you are redirecting your site urls to :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/admin [L,R=301,NC]
```

Otherwise your `/admin` URL   also redirects to `/admin` causing an endless loop.

Comment: The problem is still here, I got again ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I tried it again and again.

I replaced l8-9-10 by yours and ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS